# Transparently handle union types in function with 2 generic type parameters

Tags: typescript

Given a type `Factory<A, B>` which can be processed by a function `runFactory: <A, B>(f: Factory<A, B>): B`, how can I apply the `runFactory` function to values supplied by a generator function that produces factory values of a typed union, such as `Factory<number, string> | Factory<string, number>`?

The following code fails: ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gDwEEA0UBCAfFALxQDeUAtnANYQBqcANgK4QBcUAFAJSnFcUMKmQIIAZwlducLln4li+KAF8AUOoTIAdhOBQEqCHGAR4SNCFI9eXCynQZ9qAJY6A5jh2sqAIwhUYgAfWERHTB9-QJwXdw9iJXUoKABZUwALADpUOB0AE2QqPigMKAAGLIBWKAB+KGSUimo6RhZ2GUViQoRfCB1gLOBXYGYIPBExSWkeGbjPLqgJLLHPYAzVKC5GlMoaeiY2TlsBNMycvMLi3gnRcSkZHS4ogNRFgAMAEnIdVXeNLS6fRQVCsHQOKw2bB4Ijccj7NpHW5TKSqezhKzQgiEOwEU6Te4SbgIw7sPi8TTaPTIMYrZAebig8EY9DcIwmMwQ1m8HlAA))

```js
type Factory<A, B> = { makeValue: () => A, process: (a: A) => B }

const createFactory = (): Factory<string,number> | Factory<number,string> =>
  Math.random() < 0.5 ? 
    { makeValue: () => document.title, process: (s: string) => s.length} : 
    { makeValue: () => Math.random(), process: (n: number) => `${n}`}

const runFactory = <A, B>({makeValue, process}: Factory<A, B>): B => process(makeValue())

console.log(runFactory(createFactory()))
```

With the error message:

```
Argument of type 'Factory<string, number> | Factory<number, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Factory<string, number>'.
  Type 'Factory<number, string>' is not assignable to type 'Factory<string, number>'.
    The types returned by 'makeValue()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I cannot find a way to pass generic arguments to `runFactory` that would make this typecheck (it runs fine).

- I don't want to work with type guards in `runFactory` as I can't know the generic parameters—the `Factory` type is self-contained!
- I'd like to keep `runFactory` strongly typed, so using `any` or `unknown` is out of the question.

Note that a function with just one generic parameter would work fine, something like `runFactory<string | number>(createFactory())` would work, but I need *both* generic parameters.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't use it right! I think the problem is that the types depend on each other. I'll remove it from the title if it's not appropriate.

Comment: I don't see a good way to get this done without native support for [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#) in TypeScript.  You don't really care about `A` here per se, just that there is *some* `A` that works for each element.  And TypeScript doesn't distribute analysis across unions either, so it can't see it. Maybe you can refactor this in some way, but if you're just looking for TS to do it automatically, you're not going to be happy. Not sure how to write up an answer here other than to say "this is beyond TS's abilities"

Comment: Like, I could *try* to leverage [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which tackles a slightly different issue with unions, and that gives [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wgGJ4w), but it just will never be able to automatically work for arbitrary unions.

Comment: Or if I encode existentials I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WY28gw) but the hoops you have to jump through that turn `Factory<A, B>` into `SomeFactory<B>` are also not likely to meet your needs.  What should we do here to proceed?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, and your time! Your two suggestions have given me room to experiment on the code that my example is based on. FWIW, I'd accept an answer along the lines of "this is beyond TS's abilities"—I think that's a valid answer.

Comment: I think that first suggestion might just work, even if I need callers to provide some boilerplate, but I need some time to work through it, as the code my example is based on is considerably more complex. And it's midnight in my timezone… Thanks again for the suggestions, I do think I can make them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently beyond TypeScript's abilities to type your code both safely and ergonomically.  TypeScript doesn't really distribute its analysis over arbitrary [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types).

In order for this to work seamlessly, TypeScript would need to have direct support for so-called [existentially quantified generic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types), whereas TypeScript (and frankly most other languages with generics) only has *universally* quantified generics. That is, you'd need to be able to say "there is some type `A` such that ..." instead of "for all types `A` ...`

If we had such types, (let's say you preface the type parameter declaration by the hypothetical `exists` keyword), then every `Factory<A, B>` would automatically be considered assignable to `SomeFactory<B>`, defined by:

```
// THIS IS NOT VALID TS, DO NOT TRY THIS:
type SomeFactory<B> = <exists A>Factory<A, B>;
```

And then all you'd need to do is write

```
const runSomeFactory = <B,>(someFactory: SomeFactory<B>): B =>
  someFactory(({ makeValue, process }) => process(makeValue()));
```

(since `runSomeFactory()` really does not care about *which* `A` you're passing in; just that *there exists some* `A` that works), and you'd call it with one type argument like:

```
console.log(runSomeFactory<string | number>(createSomeFactory()));
```

And this would all be type safe and ergonomic.

But it's not part of the language.  There's a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#) for it, so maybe if it is ever implemented, we can revisit this question and give it a more satisfying answer.

But for now all we can do is work around it or give up.

---

One possible workaround is to try to encode existential generics into a `Promise`-like inversion of control flow:

```
type SomeFactory<B> = <R, >(cb: <A>(f: Factory<A, B>) => R) => R;
```

Basically, a `SomeFactory<B>` is holding a `Factory<A, B>` in a box that you can feed a callback function into and get back a result of any type you like, where the type `A` is completely unobservable from the outside. And you can package any `Factory` as a `SomeFactory`:

```
const someFactory = <A, B>(f: Factory<A, B>): SomeFactory<B> => cb => cb(f);
```

But then your `createFactory()` would need to return a union of `SomeFactory`s for it to be useful:

```
const createSomeFactory = () =>
  Math.random() < 0.5 ?
    someFactory({ makeValue: () => document.title, process: (s: string) => s.length }) :
    someFactory({ makeValue: () => Math.random(), process: (n: number) => `${n}` })
```

And then `runSomeFactory` is

```
const runSomeFactory = <B,>(someFactory: SomeFactory<B>): B =>
  someFactory(({ makeValue, process }) => process(makeValue()));
```

where you're passing the old `runFactory()` implementation in as the callback. And you can safely widen the output of `createSomeFactory()` from `SomeFactory<string> | SomeFactory<number>` to `SomeFactory<string | number>`:

```
console.log(runSomeFactory<string | number>(createSomeFactory()));
```

Hooray. That's type safe, but not ergonomic.

---

Another possible workaround to deal with any particular union of `Factory` types is to try to use the support for *correlated unions* (defined in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)) that was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

The way you can do it is to take `Factory<string, number> | Factory<number, string>` and represent it as a *distributive object type* over two base interfaces:

```
interface In { a: string, b: number }
interface Out { a: number, b: string }
type Fact<K extends keyof In = keyof In> = 
  { [P in K]: Factory<In[P], Out[P]> }[K]
```

Given the above definition, `Fact<"a">` is `Factory<string, number>`, and `Fact<"b">` is `Factory<number, string>`, and `Fact<"a" | "b">` is the union `Factory<string, number> | Factory<number, string>`:

```
type F = Fact;
// type F = Factory<string, number> | Factory<number, string>
```

And then you can write a generic function over the keys of `In`/`Out` and call it:

```
function runFact<K extends keyof In = keyof In>(f: Fact<K>): Out[K] {
  return runFactory(f); // okay
}
console.log(runFact(createFactory())); // okay
```

This also works but is fairly clunky, especially since you have to create dummy keys of `In` and `Out` which serve no purpose. If you had some way to discriminate your factory union, it would be more ergonomic.  And even though the compiler allows this as type safe, there are known and intentional soundness holes in TypeScript's type system, and you can tickle those with microsoft/TypeScript#47109 pretty easily, see [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730).

---

So that kind of exhausts my ability to suggest anything that isn't just "use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and/or [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) and don't try to get more out of TypeScript than it can handle."

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUAdghgtgpgZwA5QMZwAQGED2F1IAuArlADZkCeGA3mGBhoZUpgGJqE4BOlAPAEEANBgBCAPgwBeWhhhQA1nABq5YnABcGABQBKaZOEYk3HOgQIt2qFoH6pk0RgC+9Rs1YYAyjngdUXLx8EtIYfHAAHgCWCIQIGALi-oH8RhIA3PQMGKh4sTnccFCEcD5+nDzUMnoG2YwAssUAFgB03FAQACa+NXwYAAwtAKwYAPx1jLLySqpk6lb2kt2oxPAQhC2EUYRkcCImZoiWOsex3FEQAOaLGAgtu1eETS4YGhOMNHKKKmqaOjeNJ5tDrdGB6famczHbQQLQQVYAIzg3BuAAMACQ0CDOVEuTLZXIQfLcYgQMpwZKVULBITibQIXwUiq8LTkylBCS6LROBwTBnlAKVbTaT7TH5zPbGSFHFw3A5Q7Ri2bqPS6XT4xiEhm7e44S7aElkxns-hnC6XDAAHww8JgSO4dNQhWKpWNzMoqvV9FcIGAWWg8GQaEwAFForE4OsouQvFEYMQyMUonhaNkPOx3YIRCEZKLvsq-jUHAkIYcLFYbAkbk5XGmWJg2Zmc2EAEoiR0IrSCOkAMy0JqzYnENxbI8ymryhFubsFvGpaV7-czC653hnKWCkmLqARBhyCO0Pa9BMnBSKJUbs6q-1qkwwgNa7S6PX0fUGI3Gd8Y-KZV5FXxmX4Fj3ZZVkjDYth2SV5SOKxTkIc4rhuO4HkuJ5ZVed5pwFFJ-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)